# Portable C++98 thread class akin to std::thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, memory-management, type-safety, c++03

I want a homegrown version of C++11's `std::thread`. My motivation is to avoid manual memory management of the arguments passed to the thread function. I'm restricted to C++98. I want better type safety than what's available in the POSIX and Win32 thread APIs.

Two notes:

1. I can't think of a way to avoid a heap allocation for the thunk argument. The thread instance could be deleted before the thunk has a chance to construct its arguments. I suppose I could wait on an event in the constructor signaled by `thunk()` once the thread is in a 'ready' state, but that seems horrible.
2. I'm not too concerned about exception safety as exceptions are disabled for most of this C++ codebase.

---

```
/* There is a portable thread implementation in C available already */
int portable_thread_create(portable_thread_t *)
{
    pthread_create() **OR**
    _beginthreadex()
}

#define PORTABLE_THREAD_FUNC_DECL void *
#define PORTABLE_THREAD_FUNC_DECL unsigned int __cdecl **OR**

void portable_thread_join(portable_thread_t)
{
    pthread_join() **OR**
    WaitForSingleObject()
}

template < typename TArg0 >
class thread
{
public:
    typedef void (*function_t)(TArg0);
    thread(function_t func, TArg0 arg0)
        : m_func(func)
    {
        m_arg0 = new TThunkArg(this, arg0);
        if (0 != portable_thread_create(&m_thread, thunk, m_arg0))
        {
            delete m_arg0;
            throw new std::runtime_error("Could not create a thread");
        }
    }

    void join()
    {
        portable_thread_join(m_thread);
    }

private:
    struct TThunkArg
    {
        thread<TArg0> *Self;
        TArg0 Arg0;
        TThunkArg(thread<TArg0> *self, TArg0 arg0)
            : Self(self)
            , Arg0(arg0)
        {}
    };
    static PORTABLE_THREAD_FUNC_DECL thunk(void *unsafe_args)
    {
        TThunkArg *args = reinterpret_cast<TThunkArg*>(unsafe_args);
        try
        {
            args->Self->m_func(args->Arg0);
        }
        catch(...)
        {
            delete args;
            throw;
        }

        delete args;
        return 0;
    }
    portable_thread_t m_thread;
    function_t m_func;
    TThunkArg *m_arg0;
};
```

Comment: Aside: can you use boost? They provided a threading library before it got in the standard.

Comment: No Boost for this codebase.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put the `unsafe_args` in a `auto_ptr` so RAII can delete them safely. This is safe because you will not be copying it around.

```
static PORTABLE_THREAD_FUNC_DECL thunk(void *unsafe_args)
{
    std::auto_ptr<TThunkArg> args(reinterpret_cast<TThunkArg*>(unsafe_args));
    args->Self->m_func(args->Arg0);

    return 0;
}
```

Also don't worry about having to `new` the args; you are creating a new thread, this is much more expensive than a quick `malloc` call.

Answer (score 3):

- I don't see a reason not to make `portable_thread_create` and `portable_thread_join` static members of `thread`. If they are not meant for use outside the class, also make them private.
- `_beginthreadex`, `pthread_create` and `CreateThread` all expect a pointer to a C function. Technically, a C function is not the same as a static class member. Most sane compilers will treat them the same way, but for optimal portability, you should define you `thunk` function as a global `extern "C"`:

  ```
  extern "C" PORTABLE_THREAD_FUNC_DECL thunk(void *unsafe_args) { /* ... */ }
  ```
- [`std::auto_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/auto_ptr), even though deficient if compared to its C++11 replacements, is still cleaner and safer than raw `new/delete` in most scenarios.
- `thread` currently has no destructor, so it is not cleaning up the platform specific thread handle. I think you have a resource leak there. Also, it does not `join` or `detach` the thread on destruction. Even though this is how the standard C++ thread behaves, I would advise that you perform a default action in the destructor instead of leaving room for undefined behavior.

Comment: about point 2: or add `extern "C"` to the `PORTABLE_THREAD_FUNC_DECL` macro

Comment: The portable_thread functions are C functions from elsewhere.  Most of the C code is elided, but it's safe to say PORTABLE_THREAD_FUNC_DECL contains the extern "C" and other calling conventions for other platforms. portable_thread_detach is definitely needed, but I think join in a destructor might be confusing.